# Add stripe/line inside container above background color behind img

Tags: html, css

Attached images will clear it out ..

[image: CHECK IT HERE]

I created a container-fluid and gave it a color, then add a PNG image to be in center of that container. Now I want to add a stripe/line with another color to be above the container's background color but beneath/below the img PNG

Note that it should be responsive and full width to the container.

```css
.bg-1 {
  background-color: #79d4bd;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container-fluid1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid1 bg-1 text-center">
  <img src="nwaf.png" class="img-responsive img-circle margin" style="display:inline" alt="nwaf" width="300" height="193">
</div>
```

as Attached Images

Thanks

Comment: Got any code for us to take a look at?

Comment: .bg-1 {

      background-color: #79d4bd;
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  .container-fluid1 {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


<!-- First Container -->
<div class="container-fluid1 bg-1 text-center">
    <img src="nwaf.png" class="img-responsive img-circle margin" style="display:inline" alt="nwaf" width="300" height="193">
</div>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolutely positioned pseudo elements on the parent and `z-index` to control the overlap. You can use `top` and `translateY()` to offset the position of the stripes.

```css
.bg-1 {
  background-color: #79d4bd;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container-fluid1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container-fluid1:before, .container-fluid1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: yellow;
  height: 2.5em;
}

.container-fluid1:before {
  height: 5em;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateY(-35%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid1 bg-1 text-center">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="img-responsive img-circle margin" style="display:inline" alt="nwaf" width="300" height="193">
</div>
```

Comment: THAAAAAANKKKK YOU Michael!!! It worked Smoothly! :D .. Really appreciate your kind and helpful efforts and the quick answer!